# For loop (using .then, .catch and return) only goes through once

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot, but i am still very new. I am using the `jimp` image cropper to get an image from an url and then crop it into 5 pieces of same sizes. This is my code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.js');
var auth = require('./author.json');
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var Jimp = require('jimp');
var bot = new Discord.Client({});
bot.login(auth.token);
bot.on('message', function(message, channelID, userID, user, evt) {
  if (message.content.toString().includes(bot.user.toString())) {
    message.channel.send("Use / instead")
  }
  if (message.content.toString() == "/ping") {
    message.channel.send("pong")
  }
  if (message.attachments && message.content.toString().includes("/split")) {
    Jimp.read(message.attachments.array()[0].url)
      .then(image => {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
          return image
            .clone().crop(0, image.bitmap.height / 5 * i, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height / 5)
            .write('./files/cropped' + i + '.png')
          console.log(i);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
});
```

The `for` loop only executes once here. If I try to remove `return` and keep only image then it properly creates 5 crops, but it gives me an error:`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: `return` will stop the execution of the loop and immediately exit the function with the value you provided after the statement.

Comment: *"If i try to remove return and keep only image then it properly creates 5 crops, but it gives me and error:UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning."* Then remove it and fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been mentioned, your `for` loop and the callback it is inside of will exit the moment you execute a `return` statement.  So, if you want the `for` loop to run its course, then you have to remove the `return` statement.

You can sequence the writing of the images and make sure any errors in this specific code are logged and that there are no unhandled rejections in this code by changing your code to this:

```
bot.on('message', function(message, channelID, userID, user, evt) {
    if (message.content.toString().includes(bot.user.toString())) {
        message.channel.send("Use / instead")
    }
    if (message.content.toString() == "/ping") {
        message.channel.send("pong")
    }
    if (message.attachments && message.content.toString().includes("/split")) {
        Jimp.read(message.attachments.array()[0].url).then(async (image) => {
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                try {
                    await image.clone()
                        .crop(0, image.bitmap.height / 5 * i, image.bitmap.width, image.bitmap.height / 5)
                        .writeAsync('./files/cropped' + i + '.png');
                    console.log(`image #${i} written`);
                } catch(e) {
                    console.error(`Error writing image #${i}`, e);
                }
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
});
```